# Is there any way to get a windows application to always start on "Monitor n"?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

The specific app I'm having a problem with is Firefox but I'd like a generic solution. I have 2 monitors the larger is my main monitor.

I would like to be able to tell windows that every time I start app **'X'** I want it too start in my main monitor and ideally have it start app **'Y'** in my secondary monitor. And I want it to do this regardless of witch monitor the app was when it was last used.

Does anyone know of a tool or windows-tweak to make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you can do this with [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). Which is unfortunately pay-ware.
There's also [MultiMon](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) which has a free version. I'm not sure though it has the feature you want.

Comment: Used to use this with UltraMon, works fine

Answer (score 0):

What graphics card? Nvidia, ATI and more have their own helper-programs for managing multi-monitor setups and they're generally good and free.